# Multiple models vs. Single model for prediction

Tags: predictive-modeling, training, model-selection

I am using the Darknet Convolutional Neural Networks to detect people (as in, humans) and furniture in a single image.

If I train the model twice, one for people, one for furniture. I seem to get better results by lowering the threshold opposed to training the model once on both people and furniture.

Now my question is this: would this be considered an anti-pattern? Or is it common practice to solve my problem like this?

Comment: What is an anti-pattern?

Comment: https://sourcemaking.com/antipatterns